# Different ways of specifiying table name

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a `Book` and an `Author` entity. Only the `Book` entity is defined as a `DbSet` in the `DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

The `Author` class is a dependant of the `Book` class and not explictely listed in the `DbContext`. On database level I therefore end up with a table Books (stress on plural) for the `Book` entity, but only Author instead of Authors for the `Author` entity. Now there are at least 3 ways to specify the table name for the `Author` entity being Authors:

1. Class annotation `[Table("XYZ")]`
2. Use ModelBuilder
3. Add `Author` class explicitely as `DbSet` to `DbContext`

What are pros und cons of these different ways to achieve Authors as table name? And especially: if I list tables explicitely in the DbContext, just to pluralize there names, is there any performance loss due to this? (let's think of far more tables than just the single `Author` entity of this example that would be added to the DbContext)

Comment: #3 isn't a separate option. There's no performance loss, mostly a matter of opinion/taste *except* when you use the same DTO in different contexts. In that case you may need to use different names *and* validation rules. That's not so uncommon. Modifying an existing entity may require stricter validation rules than creating a new one.

Comment: This is opinion-based. The choice fully depends on your coding standards (if any) and preferences. BTW, option 1 and 2 also add the class to the context explicitly. I guess what you mean is 3. Add a `DbSet` property.